# Bounding inference in Bayesian network

Tags: bayesian, inference, independence, bayesian-network

I have a Bayesian network as the one depicted below, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent and uniformly distributed random variables. I know that $Y_2$ is weakly influenced by $X_1$, in the sense that $I(X_1;Y_2) \leq \delta$, $I(\cdot)$ being the mutual information. On the other hand, $Y_1$ is weakly influenced by $X_2$, which means $I(X_2;Y_1) \leq \delta$.

Now, assume that one of the links, let's say $X_2 \rightarrow Y_1$, is removed. It is clear in this case that 
\begin{align}
I(Y_1;Y_2) & \leq I(Y_1,X_1; Y_2) \\
& = I(X_1;Y_2) + I(Y_1; Y_2 | X_1) \\
& \leq \delta, \\
\end{align} 
where $I(Y_1; Y_2 | X_1)=0$ because the only path from $Y_1$ to $Y_2$ is '$Y_1\leftarrow X_1 \rightarrow Y_2$', which is a *common cause* with the middle node $X_1$ observed (d-separation). Similarly, we obtain also $I(Y_1;Y_2) \leq \delta$ if $X_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ is removed. However, if both links exist, I can write 
\begin{align}
I(Y_1;Y_2) & \leq I(Y_1,X_1; Y_2) \\
& = I(X_1;Y_2) + I(Y_1; Y_2 | X_1) \\
& \leq \delta + I(Y_1; Y_2, X_2 | X_1), \\
& = \delta + I(Y_1; X_2 | X_1) + I(Y_1; Y_2 | X_1, X_2), \\
& = \delta + I(Y_1; X_2 | X_1)
\end{align} 
where $I(Y_1; Y_2 | X_1, X_2) = 0$ by using d-separation. However, I have $I(Y_1; X_2 | X_1)$, which cannot be bounded even though $I(Y_1; X_2) \leq \delta$. Alternatively, we can write 
\begin{align}
I(Y_1;Y_2) & \leq I(Y_1; Y_2, X_2) \\
& = I(Y_1;X_2) + I(Y_1; Y_2 | X_2) \\
& \leq \delta + I(Y_1, X_1; Y_2 | X_2), \\
& = \delta + I(Y_2; X_1 | X_2) + I(Y_1; Y_2 | X_1, X_2), \\
& = \delta + I(Y_2; X_1 | X_2),
\end{align} 
but again we cannot bound $I(Y_2; X_1 | X_2)$.

**My question is, knowing that $I(X_1;Y_2) \leq \delta$ and $I(X_2;Y_1) \leq \delta$, can I say something about the dependency between $Y_1$ and $Y_2$? I would like to end up with something like $I(Y_1; Y_2) \leq \epsilon (\delta)$.**

I don't know if this problem can be tackled simply by using causal inference theory over bayesian graphs, or maybe I should use coupling theory, or anything else. So, any recommendation will be very appreciated.

[image]